# Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Backend Error [500] Errors [ Message[Backend Error] Location[ - ] Reason[backendError] Domain[global] ]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-api-dotnet-client

What am trying is to fetch the locations using google coordinate api. The code snippet I used is as follows,

```
            String serviceAccountEmail = "mail.gserviceaccount.com";

            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(Server.MapPath("../CertStore/cert.p12"), "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

            ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
               new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
               {
                   Scopes = new[] { CoordinateService.Scope.Coordinate }
               }.FromCertificate(certificate));

            // Create the service.
            var service = new CoordinateService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "sample",
            });
            var list = service.Location.List("teamId", "workermail", 1000).Execute();
```

But am getting an exception as follows,

A first chance exception of type 'Google.GoogleApiException' occurred in Google.Apis.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in Google.Apis.dll
Evaluation requires a thread to run temporarily. Use the Watch window to perform the evaluation.

stack trace

Source Error:

Line 395:                    ApplicationName = "sample",

Line 396:                });

Line 397:                **var list = service.Location.List("teamId", "workermail", 1000).Execute();**

Line 398:
Line 399:

[image: stack trace is]
Am doing anything wrong here?..

Thanks,

Anish.

Comment: Can you attach the full stacktrace? What is the exact code (line) that throws the exception?

Comment: ASP.NET uses `ThreadAbortException` to end a response so this exception is not an indication of an error. Most likely the Google API code is performing a redirect. What happens if you remove your suspicious catch/throw code? Do your code then perform as expected?

Comment: No. I just removed that try catch to get the above stack trace.